# display attribute values under desciption in table format

Tags: attributes, table

we have some 2000 products ,each product has it's own description.

I want to display attribute Label values under product's description .

assume attribute Labels are  "Phone , Computer, Television, Radio".

for product 1 & product 2....product 2000, above 4 attribute values are different.

if i enter the attribute values in admin panel , it should display those values under description in table format in frontend.

if there is only 3 attribute values for product 1, than only 3 attribute values should display under "product description".
[image: screenshot]

let me know if you need any clarifications.

thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I think Magento already offers what you need. In the default theme before 1.9 the attributes were displayed under the description if I remember correctly.

Comment: now "mobile, computer, television, radio " are texts.

but I want to make it as attributes and want to display attributes values under product description in table format as in the link....

Comment: hi marius, I attached the screenshot, let me know if you need any other details....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add attributes under `Catalog > Manage Attributes > Attributes` you can set *Visible on Product View Page on Front-end* to *yes*.

Now after adding it to the attribute set and adding values per product the attributes and their value should be displayed on the front end on the product page.

As to placing them under the description. Normally they would be placed under the **Additional information** tab so you'll have to move it. I'm going to assume you're using the RWD theme but per custom theme it may differ.

For the RWD theme you'll see the following lines of XML in the `catalog.xml` around line 224

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
</block>
```

Add the following to your `local.xml`

```
[...]
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <remove name="product.attributes"/>
    </reference> 
    <reference name="product.description">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="description_attributes" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
[...]
```

Now copy `catalog/product/view/description.phtml` for the `base/default` template to your own template and edit to include

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('description_attributes');?>
```

where ever you like your attributes. And that should be it

Comment: please check what i have done, seems i done something wrong.

catalog.xml  = http://pastebin.com/dsvubHC3

local.xml  = http://pastebin.com/vEWnSbrG

description.phtml = http://pastebin.com/uhjbEnba

help me to find what mistakes i had done.